# CSS Border Push Content Inside Div (box-sizing: border-box)

Tags: css

I have a drag-and-drop design tool (http://www.cupcard.com/designer-tool/) where I'm having some issues with user adding Text-elements on the canvas, and then adding a border on the canvas and the border then push the text-element's position.

You can try this by dragging a Text element, and then go to Layout->Border Size and slide the slider to set your size, and you will see the text element inside the canvas be pushed around.

This is because I have position: relative; on the Canvas and position: absolute; on the elements inside, so the elements inside are positioned relative to the canvas.

The reason I'm having position: relative on the Canvas is because later in the process I need to convert the HTML that the user designed, to a .pdf file that can then be printed. Therefore the position of the elements that the user designed can not be relative to the whole page itself, but need to be relative to the card that the user is designing.

Any ideas of how I can solve this issue, so that the user can set a border without pushing the content?

Comment: One idea is to use jQuery and subtract the amount of border that the #canvas has from the top: and left: attributes of all divs inside #canvas. Meaning 30px border would then take top: X-30px; to "keep" everything in same position. However, would be good if I could find a CSS solution that works everywhere.

Comment: I solved this issue by using Javascript to add margin: - (value of border-size)px; on all div's within the #canvas that had the border.

The jQuery code I used to do this was: 
`$('#canvas div').css('margin', '-' + ui.value + 'px');`

This means that if I have a border of 30 px, all div's within the element have margin: -30px; added to them.

Comment: Nice! Well played : )